# Provide list to Groovy for loop to run task multiple times

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy

i have list defined in the Groovy like:

```
all_services:[processor-create, processor-update, read-service]
```

how can i provide this list to for loop each for another stage playbook variable ${service}

```
script {

    sh("""

    ansible-playbook -i localhost, cleanup.yml --extra-vars=@${service}.yml
    """)
    ...
```

So that playbook should run if list has 2 items then it has to run 2 times for each item.

Let me put it clearly.

i have groovy script it has multiple stages:

```
stages {
    stage('Prepare') {
        agent any
        steps {
            script {
                if (params.DEPLOY_ALL_SERVICES == true){
                   all_services = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("${params.ALL_SERVICES}".split("\\+")))
                   println "all_services:" + all_services
                } else{
                   if (params.DEPLOY_ALL_EX_SERVICES == true){
                       all_ex_services = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("${params.ALL_EX_SERVICES}".split("\\+")))
                       println "deploy all ex services:" + all_account_services
                       all_services += all_ex_services
                   }
                   println "All Services:" + all_services
                }
            }
        }
    }
    stage('Create conf'){
        agent any
        steps {
            script {
                def services = "$all_services"
                println services    // it works till here, it's printing the list, if add single quotes to list then hopefully it should loop through it
                services.each {service ->
                    sh("""
                      ansible-playbook -i localhost, cleanup.yml --extra-vars=@${service}.yml
                     """)
                 }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When i execute pipeline it's able to print list on console, but am not able to provide that list into def services = "$all_services", it's not getting all the list to do the loop.

Console output println services :

```
       [processor-create, processor-update, ex-service]


an exception which occurred:
in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallEnv.locals
in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallEnv@1a3dd25b
in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ProxyEnv.parent
in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv@7f249352
in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ProxyEnv.parent
in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.LoopBlockScopeEnv@59936027
in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ProxyEnv.parent
in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv@6a3531fb
in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CallEnv.caller
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not really well enough defined to know for sure what you are looking for, but the following groovy code:

```
def services = ['processor-create', 'processor-update', 'read-service']

services.each { service -> 
  sh("ansible-playbook -i localhost, cleanup.yml --extra-vars=@${service}.yml")
}

def sh(str) {
  println "fake execution>> \n${str}\n"
}
```

demonstrates [iteration of a collection](http://groovy-lang.org/groovy-dev-kit.html#_iterating_on_a_list) and [string interpolation](http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_double_quoted_string). Saving the above in `solution.groovy` and executing it yields:

```
~> groovy solution.groovy
fake execution>>
ansible-playbook -i localhost, cleanup.yml --extra-vars=@processor-create.yml

fake execution>>
ansible-playbook -i localhost, cleanup.yml --extra-vars=@processor-update.yml

fake execution>>
ansible-playbook -i localhost, cleanup.yml --extra-vars=@read-service.yml
```

it should be noted that since the code above is using pure groovy and there is no out of the box `script` or `sh` in groovy, I have mocked the `sh` method to just print the result on stdout.

Comment: @mbjarland i have updated code in the above section, as you said by providing as list it's able to loop through it, but i have an issue to provide list to def services from "all_services"